# Azure Application Insights - recreate the singleton instance with the modified configuration

Tags: .net-6.0, azure-application-insights

I would like to track Sql command texts using Application Insights (Setting/ overriding the value of `EnableSqlCommandTextInstrumentation` in a running application) on a demand basis through a reloadable configuration. The `ConfigureTelemetryModule` of Microsoft.ApplicationInsights SDK uses singleton registration and this limits me from using IOptionsSnapshot. Can anyone please suggest me some ideas to override the config value `EnableSqlCommandTextInstrumentation` at runtime? Thank you.

**Program.cs**

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
...
var myOptions = new MyOptions();
var configSection = builder.Configuration.GetSection(MyOptions.Name);
configSection.Bind(myOptions);
builder.Services.Configure<MyOptions>(configSection);
        
builder.Services
            .AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer>(_ => new MyTelemetryInitializer(applicationName))
            .ConfigureTelemetryModule<DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule>(
                (module, _) =>
                {
                    module.EnableSqlCommandTextInstrumentation = myOptions.EnableSqlCommandTextInstrumentation;
                })
            .AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(configuration);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone please suggest me some ideas to override the config value `EnableSqlCommandTextInstrumentation` at runtime?

AFAIK, we cannot add configuration value run time to  `EnableSqlCommandTextInstrumentation`.

The  `module.EnableSqlCommandTextInstrumentation` has accept the bool value either we can enable or disable the **`EnableSqlCommandTextInstrumentation`**.

As per the [MS-Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-dependencies#advanced-sql-tracking-to-get-full-sql-query) you have to keep the settings in your host.json file **"EnableDependencyTracking": true**
**Program.cs**

```cs
builder.Services
            .AddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer>(_ => new MyTelemetryInitializer(applicationName))
            .ConfigureTelemetryModule<DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule>(
                (module, _) =>
                {
                    module.EnableSqlCommandTextInstrumentation = true;
                })
```

**host.json**

```json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": false,
        "excludedTypes": "Exception"
      },
      "dependencyTrackingOptions": {
      // Enable the Sql command text instrumentation to true to collect data
        "enableSqlCommandTextInstrumentation": true
      }
    },
```

Comment: OK thanks. Gave up on that.